# How to remove duplicate tracks from Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, duplicate-files

I have Rhythmbox 2.97 on 32bit Ubuntu 12.10.

I have a large number of duplicate music entries that don't show up in my music folder.

I really would like to know if there's any plugin or any means to get rid of them.

Answer (score 11):

It's happened to me a few times...

The easy way to solve this issue is:

1. Open "Home"
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> (this will show your hidden files and folders)
3. Navigate to `.local/share/rhythmbox`
4. Delete rhythmdb.xml
5. Restart Rhythmbox

The ***rhythmdb.xml*** file contains the music library info for Rhythmbox, by deleting it, you'll be forcing rhythmbox to re-check the library, thus getting rid of the repeated entries.

Comment: FYI: This will also reset play-counts and any star ratings you've given your songs

Comment: Did you mean simply rm ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml? Why do you complicate things?

Answer (score 9):

Some blogger wrote a GUI tool which automatically removes the duplicate entries from the rhythmbox database (without touching the actual files):

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
wget -P /tmp blog.tappir.com/rhythmboxRemoveDuplicates.py
chmod +x /tmp/rhythmboxRemoveDuplicates.py
python /tmp/rhythmboxRemoveDuplicates.py
```

Reference: http://blog.tappir.com/?p=13

Comment: Does anyone still have the above mentioned python script? That blog is down now

Comment: If `blog.tappir.com/rhythmboxRemoveDuplicates.py` doesn't download (it's down at time of commenting), the file is also available at `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chrissunny94/raspberry_pi/master/rhythmboxRemoveDuplicates.py`

Comment: Not available anymore (I get a 404 response).