# Music player that removes duplicates from library

Tags: rhythmbox, music-player

I have Rhythmbox.  This is not redundant.  I tried the solutions posted here:

[How to remove duplicate tracks from Rhythmbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278732/how-to-remove-duplicate-tracks-from-rhythmbox)

The link in the second answer is dead, unfortunately.  The first appeared to work at first but didn't.

Anybody know of a player or a program that will remove duplicates from my library?  I can't do it manually.  Deleting my rhythmdb.xml file also doesn't work.  They always come back.  It's driving me up the wall.  This is the biggest first world problem I've had to deal with all day.

Comment: XBMC doesn't have duplicates, but I can't do anything else on my machine when I open XBMC.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if the problem is Rhythmbox's own metadata or if you want to actually remove (near-)duplicate *files* from your music library.

If it's the latter, I wrote a *Duplicates Browser* plugin for [Quod Libet](http://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/) that can do that, with configurable settings and compound key to de-dupe on (e.g. `artist` plus `title` plus `album`)

[image: Quod Libet duplicates browser]